# jQuery hover - add class to current (active) div element, not others

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm currently working on a jQuery effect for a button on a website I'm developing and have run into a small issue that I can't figure out how to fix. I have written a short jQuery script to add a class to a div within the button element. It adds a hover class to an arrow next to the text for the link and removes it when you mouse out – pretty simple. However, if you look at this example ([Example](http://steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/experience/)) you'll notice that when you hover over the first button, all the arrows in the following buttons are also activated, because it adds the css class to every element on the page with that class identifier.

[Click here](http://steadfa.st/7I2S) to view a screenshot of the problem.

How do I make the script add the class to only the current arrow in the div and not all the others on the page? Here's my html, css and jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<div class="end-lft"></div>
<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>doctors/" class="btn">Visit our Doctors page</a>
<div class="end-rght-h"></div><!-- This is the element that has a hover class applied when a user hovers over a.btn above -->
```

**CSS**

```
.end-lft {
    background: url('images/ui/page/btn-lft.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 4px;
    height: 33px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

a.btn {
    background: url('images/ui/page/btn-bg.jpg') repeat-x 0 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 33px;
    padding: 6px 7px 0 7px; 
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.9em;       
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.end-rght-h {
    background: url('images/ui/page/btn-arrw-h.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 22px;
    height: 33px;
    display: block; 
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}

.end-rght-v {
    background: url('images/ui/page/btn-arrw-v.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 22px;
    height: 33px;
    display: block; 
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").hover(function() {  
        $('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v').addClass("hvr");    
    },     
    function() {    
        $('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v').removeClass("hvr");     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `next()`, as in:

```
$(this)
    .next()
    .$('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v')
    .addClass("hvr");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting on the class names, do something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $(".btn").hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v').addClass("hvr");    
    }, function() {    
        $(this).find('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v').removeClass("hvr");     
    });
});
```

The call to "find" will get the descendents of "this" (in this context, an object with the class ".btn"), so only the one in the current .btn will get toggled.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a class as a selector, so of course it will apply your new class to everything that shares either the `.end-rght-h` or the `.end-rght-v` class.

If you want to affect a single dom element, you can either use an id:

```
$('#end1').addClass(...
```

or you need to create a more specific selector:

```
$('.btn').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v').addClass('hvr');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your suggestions. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond and help. It put me on the right track. Here's what I ended up using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$(".btn").hover(function(){     
$('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v',$(this).parent()).addClass("hvr");    
},     
function(){    
$('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v').removeClass("hvr");     
});
 });
```